# Python: gevent and libfaketime

Tags: python, sleep, gevent

At work I am transitioning a system from an older version of Python, and as a part of that I need to upgrade `gevent` to version 21.1.2.

Some of our tests use `libfaketime.fake_time` and `time.sleep` in the code being tested. However, with the new `gevent` version these sleeps sleep forever, probably because time doesn't change. The `time` module does get patched.

Is there a way to make it sleep for the required period of time and then wake up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gevent.sleep` not `time.sleep`.  You can always wrap anything around a `Timeout` as well:

```
from gevent import sleep, Timeout
with Timeout(2, False) as timeout: # This will force it to move on after 2 seconds regardless
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: I tried that as well. After patching, `time.sleep` and `gevent.sleep` are identical. Turns out, I didn't set this in my configuration: `DONT_FAKE_MONOTONIC=1`. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier or removing the question

Comment: If you monkey patch, then yes time.sleep gets patched.  But you still should use the gevent modules instead for forward stability.